# Slide right and left on click of button using CSS

Tags: css, angular, typescript

[image: should slide to right and left on click of the arrow button]

On clicking of the arrow button it should slide to right and show the other element in the array.
The HTML file looks something like this.

```
<div class="showContainer" *ngIf="windowWidth <= 629">
    <div
      class="col-100 tabStyleShow row"
      *ngFor="let tabData of tabArray; let i = index"
      [ngClass]="{ completed: i <= navCount }"
    >
      <span class="col-xs-2" *ngIf="navCount > 0 && navCount <= 4"
        ><img
          src="assets/img/digital/arrow_right.svg"
          class="tab-arrow-left-show"
          (click)="slideTabPrevious()"
      /></span>
      <span class="col-xs-8 icon-title">
        <span><img [src]="tabData.active" class="tab-icon-show"/></span>
        <span
          ><div class="tab-title-show">{{ tabData.title }}</div></span
        >
      </span>
      <span class="col-xs-2" *ngIf="navCount < 4" (click)="slideTabNext()"
        ><img
          src="assets/img/digital/arrow_right.svg"
          class="tab-arrow-show"
          [ngClass]="{ arrowOpacity: i <= navCount }"
      /></span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The styles file look something like this.

```
.showContainer {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  border-radius: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
  overflow: scroll;
  text-align: center;
  .col-100 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .tabStyleShow {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    display: flex;
    .icon-title {
      display: inline-flex;
      margin-left: 70px;
      .tab-icon-show {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
      }
      .tab-title-show {
        padding-top: 18px;
        font-size: 18px;
      }
    }
    .tab-arrow-show {
      padding-top: 22px;
      padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
    .tab-arrow-left-show {
      padding-top: 20px;
      padding-bottom: 20px;
      transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
  }
  .tabStyleShow.completed {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    .tab-icon-show {
    }
    .tab-title-show {
      color: #383838;
    }
    .tab-arrow-show.arrowOpacity {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
}
```

The TypeScript file look something like this.

```
  slideTabPrevious() {
    if (this.navCount > 4) {
      this.form = !this.form;
    }
    this.navCount = this.navCount - 1;
  }
  slideTabNext() {
    console.log(this.quesArray);
    this.navCount = this.navCount + 1;
    if (this.navCount > 4) {
      this.form = !this.form;
    }
  }
```

[image: This is the next item that should appear onclick of the right arrow button]

Comment: If you only show one element, not use a *ngFor, just use, e.g. < img [src]="tabData[navCount ]" />

Comment: But then how will I get the title and other properties?

Comment: sorry, tabArray[navCount].title, tabArray[navCount].active ...

Comment: can you please paste some code snippet for the same.Sorry I am finding it difficult to follow.

Comment: it's an ungly example, but more or less: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8a9ngx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked for me. You just made my day. Any idea how to add animation for it though

Comment: Sorry, check the official doc https://angular.io/guide/animations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have time to make a little animation. The key is to have two divs but it's showed one each time. One animation spends 1000 miliseconds, the other one spends 0

Our .html is like

```
<div>
    <button *ngIf="navCount" (click)="slideTabPrevious()"><</button>
  <div *ngIf="toogle" style="display:inline" [@fadeInOut]> 
    {{tabData[navCount].img}} - {{tabData[navCount].title}}
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="!toogle" style="display:inline" [@fadeInOut]> 
    {{tabData[navCount].img}} - {{tabData[navCount].title}}
  </div>
  <button *ngIf="navCount<tabData.length-1" (click)="slideTabNext()">></button>
</div>
```

In out component we add the "animations"

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('fadeInOut', [
      state('void', style({
        opacity: 0
      })),
      transition('void => *', animate(1000)),
      transition('* => void', animate(0)),
    ]),
  ]
})
```

Finally we have a variable toogle and change this variable in clicks function

```
  toogle: boolean = false;
  slideTabPrevious() {
    this.navCount--;
    this.toogle = !this.toogle;
  }
  slideTabNext() {
    this.navCount++;
    this.toogle = !this.toogle;
  }
```

The [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8a9ngx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) with the ugly example (but animated :))

NOTE:If the two divs are in fixed positions, we can make the transition *=>void spends 100 miliseconds too

Comment: Thanks a lot and I appreciate your effort but itseems I am having an issue with "BrowserAnimationModule"

Comment: Thanks a lot. Any idea how to give a sliding effect on click

Comment: It's another aproach (and infinte carrousel) but I think it's what are you looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54008709/how-can-i-add-infinite-scrolling-to-this-angular-carousel/54013602#54013602