# How can I add infinite scrolling to this Angular carousel?

Tags: angular

I followed [this fantastic article](https://netbasal.com/building-a-simple-carousel-component-with-angular-3a94092b7080), that demonstrates how to make a simple carousel with the use of two directives and one component in Angular.

The feature set is very limited, and does not include an '**infinite scrolling**' mode, which I would like to add.

By '**inifinite scroll**' - I mean something like this jQuery equivalent:

```js
var carousel = $('#carousel'),
  threshold = 150,
  slideWidth = 500,
  dragStart,
  dragEnd;

$('#next').click(function() {
  shiftSlide(-1)
})
$('#prev').click(function() {
  shiftSlide(1)
})

carousel.on('mousedown', function() {
  if (carousel.hasClass('transition')) return;
  dragStart = event.pageX;
  $(this).on('mousemove', function() {
    dragEnd = event.pageX;
    $(this).css('transform', 'translateX(' + dragPos() + 'px)')
  })
  $(document).on('mouseup', function() {
    if (dragPos() > threshold) {
      return shiftSlide(1)
    }
    if (dragPos() < -threshold) {
      return shiftSlide(-1)
    }
    shiftSlide(0);
  })
});

function dragPos() {
  return dragEnd - dragStart;
}

function shiftSlide(direction) {
  if (carousel.hasClass('transition')) return;
  dragEnd = dragStart;
  $(document).off('mouseup')
  carousel.off('mousemove')
    .addClass('transition')
    .css('transform', 'translateX(' + (direction * slideWidth) + 'px)');
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (direction === 1) {
      $('.slide:first').before($('.slide:last'));
    } else if (direction === -1) {
      $('.slide:last').after($('.slide:first'));
    }
    carousel.removeClass('transition')
    carousel.css('transform', 'translateX(0px)');
  }, 700)
}
```

```css
$carousel-width: 600px;
$carousel-height: 300px;
body {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 22pt;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Teko';
  letter-spacing: 0.15em;
}

body * {
  -webkit-user-select: none
}

.wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: $carousel-width;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.window {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background: #222;
}

#carousel {
  width: 10000px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: -450px;
}

.slide {
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.slide#b1 {
  background: #556270
}

.slide#b2 {
  background: #4ECDC4
}

.slide#b3 {
  background: #9CE462
}

.slide#b4 {
  background: #FF6B6B
}

.slide#b5 {
  background: #C44D33
}

#prev,
#next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -40px;
  font-size: 14pt;
}

#prev {
  left: 0
}

#next {
  right: 0
}

.transition {
  transition: .7s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>INFINITE CAROUSEL</h1>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="window">
    <div id="carousel">
      <span class="slide" id="b1">SLIDE-1</span>
      <span class="slide" id="b2">SLIDE-2</span>
      <span class="slide" id="b3">SLIDE-3</span>
      <span class="slide" id="b4">SLIDE-4</span>
      <span class="slide" id="b5">SLIDE-5</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span id="prev">PREV</span>
  <span id="next">NEXT</span>
</div>
```

(the carousel can be infinitely scrolled in each direction whilst keeping the correct order of the slides)

---

I have tried a number of approaches to add this feature and none have succeeded, what I've tried (and subsequently deleted):

- Dynamically adding and removing chunks of slides either side of the currently viewed subset - i.e. if the carousel contained 3 slides I would duplicate them either side of the original `1-2-3  1-2-3, and then add/remove chunks as the user scrolls. This almost worked, the only problem was that Angular got confused when removing chunks and spun the carousel like mad, because it still had a reference to a slide number that no longer existed.
- Dynamically adding and removing single slides, similar to the above approach. Same issue.
- Straight up duplicating the slides hundreds of times. This works but is obviously horribly un-performant and seems dumb.

Here is a [stackblitz showing what I've got so far](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-carousel-example?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcarousel%2Fcarousel.component.ts).

Comment: Seems to work for me ... Do you have any issue to report ?

Comment: The carousel works, that wasn't my question - I am asking for ideas on how to add infinite scrolling to it

Comment: But you do have infinite scrolling on it ! That's why I'm asking if you have an issue, because SOF is for issues. If you want to find the best code to make an infinite scroll, I'm not sure this is the place to ask this. Try [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) maybe ?

Comment: Oh I see the issue. You don't like your carousel going back to the first slide, you would like it to consider it as a fourth slide ?

Comment: No I don't have infinite scrolling - I have something that scrolls horizontally backwards and resets when you go past the maximum or before the minimum number of slides. This is basically a bug that I am asking for help to fix.

Comment: See the example jQuery one that I included as to what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**
(before I reorder the queryList when we are in the last but one and in the second slider)

there're a work-around. The key is reorder the QueryList and change the currentSlide when you're in the last (before make a next) or the first one (before make a prev)

First change the function transitionCarrousel to allow an "animate" in 0 seconds

```
  private buildAnimation(offset, time: any) {
    return this.builder.build([
      animate(time == null ? this.timing : 0, 
          style({ transform: `translateX(-${offset}px)` }))
    ]);
  }
```

The functions next and prev becomes like

```
next() {
    //if we are in the last 
    if (this.currentSlide + 1 == this.items.length) {
      //reorder the QueryList, 
      let arr = this.items.toArray();
      let first = arr.shift();  //remove the first element
      arr = arr.concat([first]);  //Concat at last of the array
      this.items.reset(arr);
      this.currentSlide--;  //less currentSlide
      this.transitionCarousel(0); //execute the animation in 0 seconds
    }
    this.currentSlide = (this.currentSlide + 1) % this.items.length;
    this.transitionCarousel(null);
  }

  prev() {
    //If we are in the first one
    if (this.currentSlide  == 0) {
      let arr = this.items.toArray();
      let last = arr.pop();  //remove the last element
      arr = [last].concat(arr); //create an array with the last element+arr
      this.items.reset(arr);
      this.currentSlide++;  //change the currentSlide
      this.transitionCarousel(0);  //execute the animation in 0 seconds
    }
    this.currentSlide =
      (this.currentSlide - 1 + this.items.length) % this.items.length;
    this.transitionCarousel(null);
  }
```

You can see work in the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-carousel-example-a11xmn?file=src/app/carousel/carousel.component.ts)