# Is there any carousel for Angular 6 and bootstrap 3?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular6, carousel

My project runs Angular **6** and Bootstrap **3**, **NO Jquery at all**. I need to add a carousel with multiple items to scroll, but all documentation seems to use Bootstrap 4 or jquery.
Which carousel can i use that requeries Angular 6 and Bootstrap 3, without the usage of jquery?.
Thanks

Comment: In https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54008709/how-can-i-add-infinite-scrolling-to-this-angular-carousel/54013602#54013602 you has a carousel only with Angular animation and css

Answer (score 1):

please check the below stackblitz i hope it may fit for your needs and it is created using bootstrap 4. You can convert it bootstrap 3.3.7

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="dataInfo">
      <h2>Information</h2>
      <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel" data-ride="carousel" test>
          <div class="carousel-inner row w-100 mx-auto" #cara="Carousel" [animationDuration]="300">
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-4 active">
              <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/85a/daisy-s-1375598.jpg"  width="100" height="100" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-title">Card 1</h4>
                  <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                  <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-4 active">
              <div class="card">

                <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/85a/daisy-s-1375598.jpg"  width="100" height="100" alt="Card image cap"><div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-title">Card 2</h4>
                  <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                  <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-4 active">
              <div class="card">

                <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/85a/daisy-s-1375598.jpg"  width="100" height="100" alt="Card image cap"><div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-title">Card 3</h4>
                  <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                  <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
              <div class="card">

                <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/85a/daisy-s-1375598.jpg"  width="100" height="100" alt="Card image cap"><div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-title">Card 4</h4>
                  <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                  <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
              <div class="card">

                <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/85a/daisy-s-1375598.jpg"  width="100" height="100" alt="Card image cap"> <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-title">Card 5</h4>
                  <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                  <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
              <div class="card">

                <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/85a/daisy-s-1375598.jpg"  width="100" height="100" alt="Card image cap"><div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-title">Card 6</h4>
                  <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                  <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
              <div class="card">

                <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/85a/daisy-s-1375598.jpg"  width="100" height="100" alt="Card image cap"><div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-title">Card 7</h4>
                  <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                  <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a class="carousel-control-prev" role="button" (click)="cara.prev(3)">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="carousel-control-next" role="button" (click)="cara.next(3)">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>

  </div>


</div>
```

stackblitz url :  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h6a4p9

By using directives this is one way for creating it

or

if you want with out using directives below is the stack blitz url

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yaevix

This is also created using using bootstrap 4.0 but you can convert it to bootstrap 3.3.7 version

Comment: This works, thanks!. I'm trying to convert it to bootstrap 3, however i may upgrade to version 4.